# aspx page as an argument to a page

Tags: c#, asp.net

It may sound crazy but i have no choice else posting this question. One of a tester guy has raised a question where page is passed as an argument to the same page and it shows weird results.

url look like this: http://localhost:60729/default.aspx/default.aspx
Or also http://localhost:60729/default.aspx/account.aspx

Now my question is while testing this on local environment it shows resource not found 
[image]
BUT when hosted on IIS server then it does not show any resource error.
[image]

Why?? Am i missing some basic logics

Comment: Are you sure that your port is correct?

Comment: the crazy thing is it shouldnt work anywhere

Comment: what is this weird result that the tester is getting

Comment: @viveknuna port is 60729. i have edited the same.

Comment: One thing I notice is that in the URL that works, you have a slash at the end. It ends with .../default.aspx/ instead of .../default.aspx    . Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Why do you want/dont want this to work?

Comment: @GTG removing slash at end does not solve issue.

Comment: @M.Arendsen I didn't understand what you are trying to say

Comment: @Arjun If you dont want this you set something wrong in your `RouteConfig`. Can you post the code of the `RouteConfig`?

Comment: @M.Arendsen, This could the solution. Let me implement the same and respond accordingly.

Comment: @M.Arendsen,Initially i have not implemented any routing for application and after reading, [link1](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/url-routing) and [link2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx), i think this is not helping me in any case. If you could refer any link then it could be much better.

Comment: @Arjun if i am correct you have in your ASP.NET application a folder named "App_Start" inside that folder there is a class named RouteConfig, am I correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125567/discussion-between-arjun-and-m-arendsen).

Comment: Are there any IIS rewrite rules defined in the web.config of the hosted site that are not on the local server or vice versa?

Comment: Can you please highlight the visual studio and IIS Express version you are using?

Comment: @ManojAggarwal, it is a Website Application build in vs professional 2010, Hosted on iis 7.5

Comment: @VDWWD there are no such rules defined in config as i have tested by creating a entirely new application.

Comment: Do you have try use VS 2015 test ?  i have test by vs2015 it's correct both iis express and iis

Comment: @KingJk, i could test it on Vs 2015 community version. But my target project is completely developed in vs 2010 pro. This could be another headache as it may cause version issue. Hence team is working using vs 2010 pro,so i need to find out solution remaining in same environment.

Comment: you say it hosted on iis 7.5 .  it's Native IIS or IIS Express ?

Comment: i guess is version different occur problem 
refer : http://blogs.msmvps.com/bernard/2007/08/12/website-property-page-mapping-between-iis-6-and-iis-7/

Comment: Is it possible you deployed this to the IIS machine via File System and to a sub-directory called default.aspx?

Comment: On the IIS server is your default.aspx listed as the default page?  Is it listed as the default page on your localhost too?

Comment: @Liam maybe because the [Missouri Senate](http://www.senate.mo.gov/LegisLookup/default.aspx/default.aspx) does the same thing?

Comment: I think @TwistedStem called it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Routing (located in App_start) if you are using a template. Check the URL of the page (Click on the page in the Solution Explorer and check the "Browse to URL" section in the properties. Check the properties, let it start at the page (Project tab -> "Name" Properties -> Web -> Start Action -> Specific Page.). Check if it works also what the URL is. If still not working, I recommend is editing the port. This can be achieved in 2 ways.

1. Go to the Properties -> Web page and check/edit the port of localhost (under Servers -> Project URL)
2. Click on your solution in the Solution Explorer and check the url in the properties window below.

If still not working: Try editing the web.config file with this code:

```html
<system.webServer>
  <defaultDocument>
    <files>
      <clear />
      /* option 1 /*
      <add value="default.aspx/default.aspx" /> 
      /* option 2 /*
      <add value="default.aspx" />
    </files>
  </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

Also: why default.aspx/default.aspx? I think the dot in the first default could be the troublemaker here aswell.

**EDIT**

So I re-created your page (no code-behind) and here's the result:
[image: Your re-created default page]

It works on localhost perfectly. 
HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    
        This is the default page<br />
        Enter name:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        Enter Age:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I suggest, if nothing works at all, to rebuild your project. That's the only way now.

Comment: Is funny because localhost is also an IIS Server, but then on a local computer. I don't think that the installation is bad, but considering all your things you tried, you could consider reinstalling the IIS package.

Comment: Well i dnt think its an IIS issue at all. I have seen some live .aspx websites which are also with same issue. I would suggest you to try all option by urself by creating some dummy application and have a test on it. If it works then pls share abstract code.

Comment: @Arjun I am on it.

Comment: your code is working fine but have you hosted your application on IIS server and test it by passing same page as argument? The issue arrise after we host application on server. Otherwise it work fine on localhost.

Comment: Also it is not about passing same page. i am able to enter any other page as argument. But this issue is not in MVC application. There routing does its job perfectly

Comment: Application both hosted on VS server as IIS Server. Both working ok.